# Problema con el inline coditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo este código que deseo transformar en forma `inline-conditional` pero este no funciona, sin embargo en la forma normal si me funciona. ¿Cual es el problema ?

- ***Forma inline:***

```
(active === false) ? return (percentage ? "%" : "") : return ""
```

- ***Forma completa:***

```
if(active === false){
    return percentage ? "%" : ""
    }else{
      return ""
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el inline tu problema solo es la ubicación del `return`, puedes hacerlo sin necesidad de crear una variable extra:

```js
function test(active, percentage) {
  return active === false ? (percentage ? '%' : '') : '';
}
console.log(test(false, true));
console.log(test(false, false));
console.log(test(true, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

- La sintaxis del operador ternario debería estar igualada a una variable
- No debes tener el uso de `return` ya que este mismo solo existe a nivel del *scope* de una función, por lo cual tu código debería estar así:

Código

```
let op = (active === false) ? (percentage ? "%" : "") : ""
```

Y lo mandas a imprimir:

```
console.log(op)
```

Lo anterior ya con los valores asignados a `active` y `percentage` te debe hacer la op. y devolver un resultado